# View complete AXL request

Tags: node.js, soap

I'm using this library in node.js to make SOAP API calls:
https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap

These calls are being made to Cisco CUCM (VOIP application server).  This is the code I'm using.  To give context, all it's trying to do is get the details for a specific phone with getPhone method, with device name SEPAAAABBBBCCCC in this example.

```
var soap = require("soap");

var url = "AXLAPI.wsdl";
var auth = "Basic " + new Buffer("axl" + ":" + "cisco").toString("base64");
var args = {
name: "SEPAAAABBBBCCCC"
};

soap.createClient(url, function(err, client) {
    client.setEndpoint("https://192.168.138.15:8443/axl");
    client.addHttpHeader("Authorization", auth);
    client.setSecurity(new soap.ClientSSLSecurity(undefined,undefined, undefined, {rejectUnauthorized: false,},));

    client.getPhone(args, function(err,result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("soap api error is: " + err);
            console.log("last request: " + client.lastRequest);
            process.exit(1);
        }

    console.log("result is: " + result);
    });

    if (err) {
        console.log("soap client error is: " + err);
    }
});
```

It's not working.  When I print the error it only says "Error: Cannot parse response." which is not very helpful.  I thought about taking a packet capture but the application only allows for HTTPS so all traffic is encrypted.

What I want to do is log the complete packet details ie HTTP headers and XML request, and also complete HTTP response.  I know client.lastRequest will show the XML but I need to see the HTTP headers as well, since Cisco requires some custom ones.  Any ideas?

Comment: You can enable AXL trace on the CUCM, that way you can see the request and response XML in the SDI logs.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response.  The AXL trace only shows methods and not the full content.  I will try playing around with fiddler, since CUCM only allows HTTPS for axl.

Comment: I seen the full content in the AXL trace. I´ve used it many times. Maybe there is some trace parameter missing in your config? An alternative which might be a bit cumbersome in your setup is to route the AXL through something like Fiddler and decrypt the SSL.

Comment: Right, you already mentioned Fiddler... Try using "Troubleshooting trace settings", they always seem to work for me. Here's a partial sample line from the logs:
2018-03-13 00:13:57,195 DEBUG [http-bio-443-exec-32] AXLAlpha.forwardToAxis - <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><ns:getTransPatternResponse xmlns:ns="http://www.cisco.com/AXL/API/11.5"><return><transPattern uuid="{478CA631-195E-4FF0-902E-BEA5D67D9783}"><pattern>112</pattern><description/><usage>Translation</usage><blockEnable>false</blockEn

Comment: Since you are into node maybe this can be of interest also https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cisco-axl

Comment: I'll have another look at the CUCM trace setting.  I've seen that node package.  To be honest it's a waste of effort.  It's better to use a soap library.  In fact I found out (through another post on stackoverflow) that the soap library I'm using is broken.  I used strong-soap library instead and it now works.